# Linux: Comparing gcore dumps for memory leak issue

Tags: linux

Is there any way to compare two dumps taken using gcore.

e.g. gcore -o dump1  and gcore -o dump2  taken at different intervals.
How to compare these two dumps to find out memory leak issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you not use `valgrind` for finding memory leaks ?

Comment: Currently i have gcore dumps to analyze. Will try using Valgrind.